# Parsing PDF documents

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, nosql

I will try the pdf module in the link below. Assuming that works,  my question is:

Is there a way to store large text documents like a contract and be able to query information from many documents at once?

For example,  I would want to query for Termination Date or Pricing then be able to read that section for a list of contracts.

Comment: If you could refine and narrow down this question, you could also get more responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the pyPDF library for this (this is directly from [activeState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465-pure-python-pdf-to-text-converter/) web page):

```
import pyPdf

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace("\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

print getPDFContent("test.pdf")
```

This should be a good place to get started.  I have used this for automated testing of created PDFs.

Perhaps a better approach more suited to your question would be to use Microsoft's SQL Server.  They have full text search for documents (search for "SQL Server Full text search on pdf").  If you can load up all the doc's on SQL server,  you could then start using full text search to get the info you want.  This might be both easier and more flexible than the above.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. Any advice on how to store these documents? There must be a better way compared to opening in Word/Adobe and hitting Control+F

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work. For (path) do I put in my exact file location (C:\\...\Something.pdf)? I kept getting a blank content. 
I was able to use this library to select certain sheets from the PDF and create a new PDF or merge with other PDFs, but I can't figure out how to get this to create text